# Android Mediaplayer cuts beginning of file

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to play an audio file in my actvity.

The file should play in loop but the first time it plays it gets cut in the beginning for almost a second. The other times it plays correctly. I simply do the following. I also tried with prepare and onpreparedlistener but the result is the same. Any Help?

```
 MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
 mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.audio_test);
 mp.setLooping(true);
 mp.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

add the loop function to your code:

```
mp.setLooping(true);
```

for the lag are you tried it in an actual devise?

Comment: Yes, the lag is on all the devices I tried (S3, NExus5, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.audio_test);
mp.setLooping(true);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: @8mc1 Maybe something wrong about other parts of your code. Because It should be worked. I did this many times.